# Oracle virtual column or function to spot a lock on a particular row

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, rows

Does Oracle provides something like virtual column to see a lock status of a row?

In other words, I'm looking for an attribute like `LOCKED_STATUS` to distinguish between locked and not locked rows of a table, as if we could run the following query.

Don't be confused with `for update skip locked` clause, which makes the query incompilable, but is present there only to emphasise my intentions to find the specified result set.

```
  with 
    all_unlocked (LOCKED_STATUS, TITLE, ROW_ID) AS (
      select 'N' AS LOCKED_STATUS, T.TITLE, T.ROWID
        from my_table T
         for update skip locked /*DOES NOT COMPILE*/ 
    ),
    all_locked (LOCKED_STATUS, TITLE, row_id) AS (
      select 'Y' AS LOCKED_STATUS, A.TITLE, A.ROWID
        from my_table A 
       where not exists (select null 
                           from all_unlocked B 
                          where B.row_id = A.rowid)
    )
  select * from all_unlocked
    union all 
  select * from all_locked
```

Comment: Nope, there's nothing like that.

Comment: V$Lock holds lock information, but having a requirement for this seems very strange and unlikely to be a good idea - can you explain why you need this?

Comment: @Andrew, I'd like to make a bulk update on a table with optimistic locking, but without wating for locked rows, just skipping them. Also it'll be nice to collect skipped rows in one pass together with updating, i.e. without running a query to find not updated rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is a bit of a strange requirement and no Oracle version has been specified - if I assume you are in a supported version, in 11gr2 the keyword `SKIP LOCKED` was introduced. You have that above, so are you on Oracle 11gr1 or older?

If on 11gr2 or higher you would have to use it in combination with a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED though - anything you select is not locked, and anything you can select which does not exist in that set is by definition locked, although thats a considerable moving target being hit there - the reliability / consistency of it will be bad and non-repeatable.